# Is the push notification feature in the firebase not supported by node.js?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I'm currently working on the Nuxt.js + firebase project.
I succeeded in getting a token from the device from the console window after 'npm run dev'. However, when I try to 'npm run start' after 'npm run build', I can't see the token of the device in the console window.

According to Google's page, the Cloud Messaging feature is not supported on node.js. So, Nuxt.js can't write the push notification feature on the firebase?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#namespace

Comment: In general, it's easier to help if you include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to send a push notification to a node.js script? Or are you trying to send a push notification *from* a node.js script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running node scripts with `npm run dev`, you can see various bits of debugging information that normally won't appear when you use `npm run start`.

In your case, it appears that when in the `dev` mode, the FCM ID token is being logged to console.

To log the token to console in a similar fashion, you can use the following code:

```js
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.getToken()
  .then((currentToken) => {
    console.log("Current FCM ID Token: " + (currentToken || "UNAVAILABLE"))
  }), (err) => {
    console.error(err)
  });
```

While logging is useful for debugging, use [`getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#getToken) without logging it in the console in your production code.

The [FCM Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) and it's example project [`firebase/quickstart-js/messaging`](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging) have further information and sample code on the topic.